# How to get a property value from an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, foreach

I want to make an array with country names from a JSON file which contains an array of objects. These objects have a property **name** with the name of the country, which is what I need.

This is my JavaScript code which returns a list of **undefined** instead of country names:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const getTeamsFromUrl = async() => {
    const url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/keeguon/2310008/raw/bdc2ce1c1e3f28f9cab5b4393c7549f38361be4e/countries.json';
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const listOfCountries = response.data;

    // this console.log prints properly the array of objects
    // console.log(listOfCountries);

    for (let i = 0; i < listOfCountries.length; i++) {
        console.log(listOfCountries[i].name);
    }
}

console.log(await getTeamsFromUrl());
```

In the other hand, if I use **forEach**, I get this error message:
*listOfCountries.forEach is not a function*

```
let x = listOfCountries.forEach(country => {
     console.log(country.name);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be aware that for each doesn’t return anything

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I'm using a console.log() in forEach for testing. It should to return something, right?

Comment: foreach should be working here but it might happen that in some cases the `response.data` is not an array so you should check that.

Comment: @lix it should be logging yes, but if you want any data back try swapping forEach with map. In your example `x` will always be undefined.

Comment: You'll need to show a sample of your data to get help on this.

Comment: @NenadVracar, the commented `console.log(listOfCountries)` line print an array of objects so `response.data` seems to work

Comment: response.data is probably a string, you need to parse it first, for loop is working on the string and not the array, JSON.parse(listOfCountries), but it seems to has it's own problems

Comment: @Ashu, I've tried before to `JSON.parse(listOfCountries)` but I get this error: `JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: I validated the json on the validator site, seems it's an invalid json https://jsonlint.com/, can you please copy and validate it for yourself

Comment: This is not valid json. Properties are not wrapped in quotes

Comment: REALLY? I didn't imagine that was possible. Thank you very much anyway @Ashu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "JSON" from the original gist is valid **JavaScript**, not **JSON**. You could (but don't) run the text through `eval` to obtain an `Array` object. Better still would be to download it and use it on the RHS of an assignment statement, possibly to convert it to JSON if you wanted to save it somewhere:

```
let listOfCountries =  paste-raw-downloaded-gist-content-here; // assign as an array literal
let json = listOfCountries.stringify();         // serialize as JSON text
```

The reasons why the JavaScript is not valid JSON are

1. property names have to be in double quotes, as in `"country"` and `"code"` instead of being unquoted,
2. string values need to be in double quotes, as in `"Åland Islands"` and `"AX"` instead being single quoted.

Trying to simplistically convert the gist into JSON with string replacements can lead to problems with the back slash escaped single quote in `'Cote D\'Ivoire'` that using the gist in JavaScript source avoids.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine but your source json was invalid. This is tested an it works from another source.

```
const getTeamsFromUrl = async() => {
    const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samayo/country-json/master/src/country-by-name.json';
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const listOfCountries = response.data;

    // this console.log prints properly the array of objects
    // console.log(listOfCountries);

    for (let i = 0; i < listOfCountries.length; i++) {
        console.log(listOfCountries[i].country);
    }
}
getTeamsFromUrl();
```

Comment: You're completely right. I've tested with another JSON file and it works like a charm. Thanks @Ozgur

Comment: It seems it is necessary to replace all single quotes by double ones in the initial JSON.

Comment: @VasiliiKovalev yes, also property names even didn't have quotes.

Comment: If you want to fix it fast, you can use https://jsonformatter.org/. A button with wrench icon does it.

Comment: lix doesn't have access to the source json. It is just a file on someone's github account. However Rick N provided a good answer to that on how to fix the json

Comment: Oh, OK, got it.

Answer (score 1):

response.data is returning a string that needs to be parsed into an array.  It's also returning a string that isn't valid JSON, so needs a little bit of work on it to create valid JSON.

The code below does this from your original URL and prints out the country names:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const getTeamsFromUrl = async () => {
    const url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/keeguon/2310008/raw/bdc2ce1c1e3f28f9cab5b4393c7549f38361be4e/countries.json';
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const listOfCountries = response.data;
    const jsonListOfCountries = listOfCountries.replace(/name:/g, '"name":').replace(/code:/g, '"code":').replace(/'/g, '"');
    const countries = JSON.parse(jsonListOfCountries);
    for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        console.log(countries[i].name);
    }
}

(async function MyFunc() {
    console.log(await getTeamsFromUrl());
})();
```